# TJWSEmbeddedJaxrsServer and ContainerRequestFilter

Tags: groovy, resteasy, spock

I am writing an integration test based on Spock to test our REST API using the JAX-RS Client API and the `TJWSEmbeddedJaxrsServer`. Everything work very smooth so far but now I would like to write my test integrating a server request filter.

Since my `@Provider` classes that are implementing the `ContainerRequestFilter` interface are not discovered and called at runtime I wanted to ask how I have to register this filter class manually?

Can you give me any hint on this one?

```
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:applicationContextRestIntegrationTest.xml")
@ActiveProfiles(['local', 'compliance'])
@TestExecutionListeners([DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class])
class RestSpec extends Specification implements JaxrsInterceptorRegistryListener  {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext
    @Autowired
    KsdApiSchemaRequestFilter filter

    @Override
    void registryUpdated(JaxrsInterceptorRegistry registry) {
        println "XXXX"
    }

    void "test the rest api"() {

        given:
        EmbeddedJaxrsServer server = new TJWSEmbeddedJaxrsServer()
        server.port = 9999
        server.start()

        def dispatcher = server.getDeployment().getDispatcher()
        //dispatcher.registry.getResourceInvoker()
        dispatcher.providerFactory.clientRequestFilters.listeners.add(this) // would like to register an instance of MethodResourceInvoker
        dispatcher.providerFactory.clientRequestFilters.registerSingleton(filter)
        dispatcher.registry.addResourceFactory(new SpringResourceFactory('complianceTestResource', applicationContext, ComplianceTestResource.class))

        def url = 'http://localhost:9999//v1/compliancetest'

        def client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().property('connection.timeout', 1).register(JacksonJsonProvider.class).build()

        when:
        Response response = client.target(url).request(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).options()

        then:
        response.status == 200

        cleanup:
        server.stop()
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1**
My `ContentRequestFilter` is a Spring Bean and therefore I have to register the instance of the Spring bean.

`clientRequestFilters.registerSingleton(..)` actually registers my filter but since the underlaying `MethodResourceInvoker` is not registered as a `listener` in the `registry` and the registry uses this [invoker](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/3.0.10.Final/jaxrs/resteasy-jaxrs/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/core/SynchronousDispatcher.java#L171) at runtime, the `registerSingleton` does not get [propagated](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/3.0.10.Final/jaxrs/resteasy-jaxrs/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/core/ResourceMethodInvoker.java#L148).

Is there a way to get an instance of this `MethodResourceInvoker` in my Spock test? I need it to add it to the listener list of the `clientRequestFactory` (see my listing above)

Comment: have you tried `dispatcher.providerFactory.register(RequestFilterClass)`

Comment: @LeonardBrünings take a look at my edit.

Comment: try `dispatcher.providerFactory.register(requestFilterInstance)`, clientRequestFilters are only used for the client side not for your server.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings Thank you. This does the job. Would you like to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `dispatcher.providerFactory.register(requestFilterInstance)`, clientRequestFilters are only used for the client side not for your server.

`providerFactory.register()` can be used for both classes and already configured instances, e.g., SpringBeans.